# Geolocation querying returns random values in mongod;

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, coordinates, geospatial, querying

I am trying to use mongodb $near operator to get some documents from database according to user's position.

So, after i've got user coordinates, i query a collection which has the right geospatial index ensured before :

```
computed_places.ensureIndex({'geoJson.coordinates' : "2d"}, function(err,ok) {)
```

with this query:

```
computed_places.find({'geoJson.coordinates' :
                         {$near:
                            {$geometry:
                                {type : "Point" ,
                                 coordinates:[user.longitude , user.latitude]}},
                              $maxDistance : 200
                              }})   
                              })
```

But after the first test it sounds returning random documents, as i've input

```
longitude: 11.870853799999999,
latitude: 45.4109512
```

And documents returned had this values (one pair for each document, which is the content of 'geoJson.coordinates' field):

```
[7.42149, 9.00046 ]
[ -1.50372, 12.3791 ]
[ 15.30972, -4.41944 ]
[ 15.0444, 12.1047 ]
[ -16.27479, 12.58644 ]
[ -16.47951, 14.69669 ]
[ -16.96598, 14.79575 ]
[ -17.46682, 14.68189 ]
[ -17.45258, 14.69922 ]
[ -17.46331, 14.68731 ]
[ -17.46232, 14.69187 ]
[ -16.42596, 16.06252 ]
[ 29.74278, -2.61611 ]
[ 30.06219, -1.95994 ]
[ 30.21835, 0.67669 ]
[ 30.27613, 0.65909 ]
[ 30.65717, -0.61551 ]
[ -9.54612, 30.40618 ]
[ 32.01435, 0.0026 ]
[ 32.01889, 1.8425 ]
[ 32.31678, 2.78819 ]
[ 32.56815, 0.33572 ]
[ 32.57702, 0.33791 ]
[ 32.58911, 0.41068 ]
[ 32.59748, 0.32096 ]
[ 32.62691, 0.34929 ]
[ 32.6354, 0.26048 ]
[ -8.02018, 31.64532 ]
[ -8.01542, 31.64902 ]
[ -4.97333, 34.06444 ]
[ -6.86187, 33.98307 ]
[ -6.8614, 33.98705 ]
[ -1.89851, 34.65022 ]
[ -6.80016, 34.04182 ]
[ 35.08467, 0.25603 ]
[ 31.053, -17.784 ]
[ 33.99323, -11.422 ]
[ 32.54222, 15.61222 ]
[ -5.89351, 35.73639 ]
[ 33.52946, 14.38584 ]
[ 36.82248, -1.27937 ]
[ -4.47724, 36.71546 ]
[ -6.29799, 36.53392 ]
[ -3.60341, 37.17572 ]
[ -3.6021, 37.17812 ]
[ -3.60446, 37.18048 ]
[ -3.59712, 37.1935 ]
[ -3.59772, 37.20488 ]
[ -5.99051, 37.3808 ]
[ -6.06589, 37.37031 ]
[ -1.17451, 38.02272 ]
[ 28.1617, -25.7322 ]
[ -3.46826, 37.99136 ]
[ -4.80046, 37.86933 ]
[ -4.78746, 37.87324 ]
[ -4.78191, 37.88005 ]
[ -4.7673, 37.8851 ]
[ -0.68716, 38.27538 ]
[ 27.99889, -26.18333 ]
[ -0.51224, 38.38446 ]
[ 18.8647, -33.9301 ]
[ 38.50135, 7.06233 ]
[ -9.19215, 38.6979 ]
[ 38.75917, 9.04667 ]
[ -9.11664, 38.7562 ]
[ -0.06884, 39.99415 ]
[ 27.72312, -29.45066 ]
[ -5.6689, 40.96603 ]
[ 2.16353, 41.38636 ]
[ 2.11051, 41.39367 ]
[ 0.62332, 41.60818 ]
[ 32.5833, -25.9667 ]
[ 32.58496, -25.974 ]
[ 32.59976, -25.95979 ]
[ -0.88738, 41.68331 ]
[ -8.39647, 41.56104 ]
[ -5.5597, 42.61231 ]
[ 29.89667, 31.19626 ]
[ 29.90528, 31.20194 ]
[ 31.20797, 30.02733 ]
[ 29.9989, 31.26448 ]
[ 25.10237, 35.31901 ]
[ 31.22038, 30.0574 ]
[ 31.23613, 30.04574 ]
[ 31.2625, 30.04583 ]
[ 5.44321, 43.23243 ]
[ 5.44209, 43.23268 ]
[ 5.35897, 43.29198 ]
[ 5.40025, 43.28711 ]
[ -5.77641, 43.24242 ]
[ 5.38261, 43.29817 ]
[ 5.37486, 43.29979 ]
[ 5.39214, 43.30123 ]
[ 5.37923, 43.30398 ]
[ -3.79904, 43.47363 ]
[ 5.39339, 43.30592 ]
[ 5.45815, 43.31909 ]
[ 5.41609, 43.33851 ]
[ 31.60639, 30.15028 ]
[ 22.37148, 37.52703 ]
```

That results seem random compared to my input, but also among themselves. What am i doing wrong? This is the strcture of queried documents:

```
doc = {
  "geoname_id": 6269578
, names: {
    en: "Pedagogical University"
  }
, country: "VN"
, geoJson: {
    type: "Point"
  , coordinates: [
      106.68259
    , 10.76154
    ]
  }
, timezone: "Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh"
, "_id": new ObjectID("530dffbe734e07e50d9b5ef9")
};
```

Comment: uuu illumination.. maybe do i have to use 2dsphere index?